# Python Threading simple program

Tags: python, multithreading

I have two functions:
1) `a = f(w) = w+1 , wait(.5 sec)`
2) `w = g(A) = mean(A)+1, wait (30 sec)`

I have to write a python function that:
Init

```
w = 1
A = []
1) Runs a = f(w) after every 1 sec. and append: A.append(a)
2) Runs w = g(A) after every 1000 sec.
```

We can see above that g(A) takes more than 30 sec to execute (wait for 30 sec). So, we don't want to wait for w = g(A) to be completed before running a= f(w). Just use the latest value of w whichever available to run, a = f(w)

Can you please help to write this function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). SO isn't really a 'write my code for me' service, so it would help you greatly if you presented some code with an actual problem. In its current form, your question is likely to get deleted, unfortunately. Also, as a Python-specific aside, you'll probably want to use multiple processes rather than threads due to the global interpreter lock.